# Add unallocated space to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: partitioning

I have this situation on my hd:

[image]

I would increase the space of sda10 with the double unallocated space. There is a way to do that?

Comment: Use `gparted live CD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your image from a Live CD you can do expand the space to the unallocated partitions with this consideration.

First you can't have anything between the partition you want to expand to.  So you would have to delete the `/dev/sd9` (Linux swap partition).  Then expand `/dev/sd10` to include the space unallocated space on that side.  Do the same for the unallocated space on the other side.

As far the swap partition, I would suggest that you put it to the furthest on the end.  This way you won't face having it separate your other partitions that you might have occasion to want to grow or shrank.

Comment: How can I delete the swap partition and then restore It?  After that I Can expand /dev/sda10 in both sides, left (50GiB) and right (1.59GiB)?

Comment: @SaraCaruso  You don't delete/restore, per se.  Just delete it.  It's temporary space that is only used when the OS is running.  So while you are performing this type of maintenance (working in the LiveUSB session), it's not being used.  So just remove it.  After you have organized your disk (resize, move, etc), then create a new swap partition at your desired size.  While you are arranging your partitions, just create a new one to the furthest to the right.  The main thing is to remove it so that you can have continuous space for resizing your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: So after that I erase /sda9 I will have unallocated space on both left and right. Right click on /sda10 and resize to encompass the two unallocated partitions (50 + 1,59 GiB) and the old swap area (5 GiB). In the end it will be only /sda10 of 45+56,59GiB, right? then I will right-click on It to reduce of 5GiB to create a new swap space so that it appears as the last entry. Did I get it right?

Comment: @SaraCaruso Yes.

Comment: Thank you for tour help. I've done everything. I ask you last thing:  how can I delete the Kali choice from GRUB? I delete his partitions and with GRUB customizer there isn't già voice but I still have that choice in the GRUB menù, why?

Comment: From the **Terminal** run `sudo update-grub`.  Then reboot.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following steps to solve your problem:

1. Boot from a live CD/USB, and choose <kbd>try without installing</kbd>.
2. Open the dash once you are in the desktop, and type `gparted` and open the app. It will take a while to find all the partitions so *be patient*.
3. Right-click and choose move and drag and drop the Linux swap onto the small partition all the way at the right.
4. Right-click on the Ubuntu partition and choose <kbd>resize</kbd> and drag one side all the way to take up all of the unalocated space.

### You're done!